# Python: Logger failing to log object

Tags: python, logging

Here is the logger configuration

```
APPLICATION_NAME = 'myapp'

# -- setting up global logger - #
logger = logging.getLogger(APPLICATION_NAME)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler(APPLICATION_NAME + '.log')

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(messages)s')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Here is how I am using it

```
logger.debug('added transaction: %s', str(transaction))
```

Where `Transaction` is an entity and `__repr__` looks like

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Transaction:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s>' % (
        self.uuid, self.name, self.created_on, self.amount,
        'debit' if self.debit else 'credit', self.user, self.category)
```

My server log says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 842, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 719, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 467, in format
    s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'messages'
Logged from file transaction_manager.py, line 30
```

What is I am not doing right here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `%(message)s` rather than `%(messages)s`.

See the [Basic example](http://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/minimal-example.html) in the documentation.